# Send a textbox inside an email and make a button to open a link with the textbox value in the querystring

Tags: php, magento

I am doing an email ad that resembles my website, but my website has a search box.

I wonder if its possible to include a text box in the email and when they click one image, it opens a page with a query string depending on what they typed.

mydomain.com/q=yoursearchkeyword.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to incorporate a HTML form inside the mail body. Of course you should send a HTML mail, not plain text.

```
<form action="http://mydomain.com/" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <input type="image" src="http://mydomain.com/path/to/image.jpg" />
</form>
```

Have in mind that there are some mail clients that do not / cannot parse HTML forms. Also have in mind that mail providers might block your mail and mark it as SPAM for using forms inside of it.